# What's the Option=N in the MySQL ODBC connection string?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, odbc, connection-string

I have seen both `Option=3` and `Option=4` in connection string samples for MySQL ODBC but no explanation or documentation. What do those numbers mean?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `Option=` value is the sum of the numeric values for various flags that specify how Connector/ODBC should work. Its default value is 0.

From an older version of the Connector/ODBC documentation at [web.archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20120120203736/http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-odbc-configuration-connection-parameters.html):

`Option=3;` corresponded to `FLAG_FIELD_LENGTH` (1) + `FLAG_FOUND_ROWS` (2)

`Option=4;` was `FLAG_DEBUG`

According to the current list of Connector/ODBC options here ...

[Table 5.2 Connector/ODBC Option Parameters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-configuration-connection-parameters.html#codbc-dsn-option-flags)

... both `FLAG_FIELD_LENGTH` (1) and `FLAG_DEBUG` (4) have been removed.

MySQL also recommends using the parameter names instead of (the sum of) their numeric values, not only for clarity, but because not all options *have* numeric values. So, instead of

`Option=2;`

we should use

`FOUND_ROWS=1;`

Comment: This was a life saver. I went from MySQL ODBC version 5.3.4 to 5.3.6 and the `Option=3` in the connection string was all of a sudden throwing "**MySQL Server has gone away**" errors when I tried to open a recordset off of the connection (even thought the connection seemed to open fine). I changed the option part to `FOUND_ROWS=1` and everything is now working fine. Thanks again!