# MySQL ODBC configuration

Tags: mysql, odbc

I have managed to make my Access work as a frontend for MySQL. 
I have managed to make it work through connection string but because some specifics in code i would like to save DSN configuration as user DSN.

I have ran into one specific problem. I need to use `option=3` inside my connection string because without `option=3` i get error: `The Microsoft Jet database engine stopped the process because you and another user are attempting to change the same data at the same time.` 
If i include option=3 in my connection string everything works well. The thing is, in Mysql Connector/ODBC data source configuration i do not know which checkbox/option represents `option=3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The doc about this is here : [Connector/ODBC Connection Parameters](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-configuration-connection-parameters.html#codbc-dsn-option-flags)

`option=3` looks deprecated as specified in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407841/whats-the-option-n-in-the-mysql-odbc-connection-string) :

> `Option=3;` corresponded to `FLAG_FIELD_LENGTH` (1) +
>   `FLAG_FOUND_ROWS` (2)

It looks indeed deprecated as in the doc I can't find any reference to `FLAG_FIELD_LENGTH`

We can thus assume that the flag you really need is `FLAG_FOUND_ROWS`

According to the doc, the GUI option for this flag is

> Return matched rows instead of affected rows

[image]